# Objective-C Call method waiting for respond before proceed to next code

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

Any code to pause and resume after get BOOL ?

```
-(void)methodOne{
    [self methodTwo]; <----- what should I code here to "pause and waiting respond? 
    /// other coding
}
```

============== UPDATE ============

I wish to call methodTwo, wait for the return BOOL before I proceed to /// other coding

Comment: do want to call that method after some time ? Please write the detail question what you exactly want

Comment: That is default behaviour if you do not go out of your way to make methodTwo asynchronous. Just remember to assign the BOOL to something when the method returns. BOOL b = [self methodTwo];

Comment: Can you please post the code for methodTwo so we can see what is going on there.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of answers here, making it too complex without a reason.

As @samfisher mentioned, if your methodTwo does not run async code, then the execution is serial, which means your code in your methotOne function will be executed after methodTwo has been completed.

In case you have async code, then the obvious and easy solution is to split methodOne in 2 separate functions:

```
-(void)methodOne{
    //previous code execution here
    [self methodTwo];
}

- (void)afterMethodTwo(BOOL)resultsFromMethodTwo {
    /// other coding
}
```

and in methodTwo, call in the afterMethodTwo function and pass your boolean variable, like this:

```
[self afterMethodTwo:myBool];
```

This is the simplest and cleanest approach, as any other approaches make the code unnecessary complex.

Answer (score 1):

just make sure that your `methodTwo` does not have any async execution

Answer (score 1):

use 'performSelectorOnMainThread' like this, the important is to set 'waitUntilDone' to 'YES':

```
-(void)methodOne
{   

//  [self methodTwo];// <----- what should I code here to "pause and waiting respond?
    /// other coding

    NSNumber *isDone = [self performSelector:@selector(methodTwo) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

    NSLog(@"%i", [isDone boolValue]);

}

-(NSNumber*)methodTwo
{

    return [[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: Initializing 'NSnumber *_strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'void'

Comment: you are trying to convert void value into NSNumber. Please paste your code for reference.

Answer (score 0):

use 'performSelectorOnMainThread' like this, the important is to set 'waitUntilDone' to 'YES':

```
-(void)methodOne{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(methodTwo) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    /// other coding
}
```